# Symfony's autogenerated model classes' function location

Tags: symfony1, model, propel

i'm working on a symfony project and i generated a set of model classes called `Base<name>.php`, `<name>.php`, `<name>Peer.php` and `Base<name>Peer.php`

I did the famous jobeet tutorial and i still have doubts about locating functions in these files of the model. So my question is:

What kind of functions i have to put in which file?

or expressed other way

How i know where to locate a function in these files?

thank you very much

Comment: The two first filenames look very strange to me... as if you created an anonymous model. Could you show the corresponding `schema.yml` file?

Comment: i was using the nomenclature Base<name>Peer instead of Base"name"Peer. For some reason with the first one the text inside the '<' '>' doesnt appear in the question :S

Comment: I'm going to edit your question to show you how you can use the first nomenclature. Most of the online editors remove unknown tags

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should never edit the files prefixed with `Base`, they can be overwritten if you change something in your schema and regenerate these files.

The custom methods you are writing yourself should be in the `Peer` class.

To easily locate a method, I use a good IDE like PDT that parses the files and allows searching methods.

Comment: an what about the <name>.php file? what kind of functions goes there?

Comment: @sirAndreu Your custom functions (everything you write by hand, yourself). For instance, the Peer.php file contains the `Peer` class. That was the purpose of my second sentence